# Trigger not working, why?

Tags: mysql, trigger

What i'm doing wrong?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Calc` AFTER INSERT on `test`.`bookings` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE `test`.`article` AS `ST`
SET `ST`.`stock` = SUM(`test`.`bookings`.`amount`)
WHERE `ST`.`articlenr` = `test`.`bookings`.`NEW.article`;
END
```

The idea is, to calculate "STOCK" in ARTICLE, after an insert like:

```
Amount: 1 Article: 123
```

on table bookings.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Try: `SET ST.stock = ST.stock + NEW.amount
WHERE ST.articlenr = NEW.article;`

Comment: No, that would be wrong. Because it should calculate the sum of all bookings, what happens if i delete one?, then is the stock wrong

Comment: @user3101966 actually it would be wrong your way, too, until the next insert; if you're going to keep denormalized data, you have to maintain it wherever you manipulate the source... so you need update and delete triggers, too, not just insert.

Comment: You'll need a `DELETE` trigger, too, anyway. What do you think your code will do (even if corrected to calculate over all bookings) after a booking is deleted (and until a new one is inserted - which may happen days later)?

Comment: No, the delete-booking is like Set amount to 0, and set a flag named "deleted", to see that this was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a trigger for each operation on your table: Insert, Update and Delete

To demonstrate, I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e89/1)

First let's create the tables and the triggers:

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings(id INT, articlenr INT, amount INT);
CREATE TABLE article(articlenr INT, stock INT);

//

CREATE TRIGGER Calc_INS AFTER INSERT on bookings FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE article AS A
     SET A.stock = A.stock + NEW.amount
   WHERE A.articlenr = NEW.articlenr;
END;

//

CREATE TRIGGER Calc_UPD AFTER UPDATE on bookings FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE article AS A
     SET A.stock = A.stock - OLD.amount
   WHERE A.articlenr = OLD.articlenr;

  UPDATE article AS A
     SET A.stock = A.stock + NEW.amount
   WHERE A.articlenr = NEW.articlenr;
END;

//

CREATE TRIGGER Calc_DEL AFTER DELETE on bookings FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE article AS A
     SET A.stock = A.stock - OLD.amount
   WHERE A.articlenr = OLD.articlenr;
END;
```

Because of a SQLFiddle limitation we also need procedures to insert, update and delete bookings. Note that these are not required to make the triggers work, only to make SQLFiddle work...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_booking(
  pId INT,
  pArticlenr INT,
  pAmount INT
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO bookings VALUES(pId, pArticlenr, pAmount);
END;

//

CREATE PROCEDURE change_booking(
  pId INT,
  pArticlenr INT,
  pAmount INT
)
BEGIN
  UPDATE bookings 
     SET articlenr = pArticlenr,
         amount = pAmount
   WHERE id = pId;
END;

//

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_booking(
  pId INT
)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM bookings 
   WHERE id = pId;
END;
```

Finally we need some articles:

```
INSERT INTO article VALUES(1,0);
INSERT INTO article VALUES(2,0);
```

Now let's look at our current inventory:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM article;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e89/1/0)**:

```
| ARTICLENR | STOCK |
|-----------|-------|
|         1 |     0 |
|         2 |     0 |
```

There is currently no stock available. To change that lets create a booking and check the inventory again:

**Query 2**:

```
CALL add_booking(100, 1, 21);

SELECT * FROM article;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e89/1/1)**:

```
| ARTICLENR | STOCK |
|-----------|-------|
|         1 |    21 |
|         2 |     0 |
```

As you can see, the stock was updated correctly. Because the `add_booking` procedure executes an `INSERT` statement, the `calc_INS` trigger fired and updated the inventory.

To see that this works with multiple bookings for the same article let's create three additional ones of them:

**Query 3**:

```
CALL add_booking(200, 2,  42);
CALL add_booking(201, 2, 101);
CALL add_booking(202, 2, 210);

SELECT * FROM article;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e89/1/2)**:

```
| ARTICLENR | STOCK |
|-----------|-------|
|         1 |    21 |
|         2 |   353 |
```

Again, all actions were `INSERT`s, so only the `calc_INS` trigger fired.

Now let's change the amount on one of the bookings:

**Query 4**:

```
CALL change_booking(201, 2, 1);

SELECT * FROM article;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e89/1/3)**:

```
| ARTICLENR | STOCK |
|-----------|-------|
|         1 |    21 |
|         2 |   253 |
```

`change_booking` executes an `UPDATE` statement. This causes the `calc_UPD` trigger to fire. In that trigger the first `UPDATE` statement removes the old amount from the inventory. The second `UPDATE` then adds the new amount to the inventory.

I implemented this as two separate update statements to allow for the article to be changed on a booking:

**Query 5**:

```
CALL change_booking(201, 1, 1);

SELECT * FROM article;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e89/1/4)**:

```
| ARTICLENR | STOCK |
|-----------|-------|
|         1 |    22 |
|         2 |   252 |
```

The first `UPDATE` in the `calc_UPD` trigger removed (subtracted) the amount from the article 2 and the second `UPDATE` then added the new amount to article 1.

You said you are using only soft deletes. Soft deletes can be handled by the update trigger. For completeness sake I included a delete trigger in this example anyway.

**Query 6**:

```
CALL delete_booking(100);

SELECT * FROM article;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e89/1/5)**:

```
| ARTICLENR | STOCK |
|-----------|-------|
|         1 |     1 |
|         2 |   252 |
```

`delete_booking` executes a `DELETE` statement. That causes the `calc_DEL` trigger to fire. It subtracts the old amount from the article's inventory.

Instead of trying to keep the stock in sync with the bookings you could also create a view that joins the articles table (without the `stock` column) with the bookings table to calculate the stock on the fly when needed. This sounds like a lot of overhead, but it is not actually that bad if you use the right indexing strategy and it is a lot easier to maintain in the long run than triggers.

Such a view could look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW stock
AS
SELECT A.articlenr , COALESCE(SUM(B.amount),0) AS stock
  FROM article AS A
  LEFT JOIN bookings AS B
    ON A.articlenr = B.articlenr
 GROUP BY A.articlenr;
```

Here is [another SQLFiddle that demonstrates the view without triggers](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15cf5/4).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your the detailed explanation of this. I used this as the working solution. I modificated the Update Line to a SUM-function instead of a + function, in my Trigger.  

Thank you!